# How do I pre parse a JSON String?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to feed this JSON URL to another site

http://naturetrek.co.uk/blog/api/get_recent_posts/

But the problem is that because of the initial three `<p>` tags its not valid JSON, you can check this in here...

http://jsonlint.com/

if u remove these 3 tags, it becomes valid.

We cant change the JSON string output from the Naturetrek Blog.

In our own code we use the following....

```
<h2>Naturetrek BLOG</h2>
<div id="ntblog"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var blogURL = "http://naturetrek.co.uk/blog/api/get_recent_posts/";

        $.getJSON(blogURL, function(info) {

            alert("here");
            var output = info.status;

            /*
            for (var i = 0; i <= info.posts.length - 1; i++) {
            output += '<li>' +
            '<a href = "' + info.posts[i].url +
            '">' + info.posts[i].title + '</a></li>';

            }
            */

            var ntblog = document.getElementById('ntblog');
            ntblog.innerHTML = output;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The alert never gets called, because the JSON is invalid JSON. MY QUESTION IS -- IS THERE A WAY TO PREPARSE THE JSON TO REMOVE THE THREE `<p>` TAGS, SOMEHOW? OR ANOTHER WAY U CAN THINK OF?

Comment: You should rather ask them to fix their JSON …

Answer (score 2):

$.getJSON is just shorthand for:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

See documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Just use $.ajax change dataType to "html" and parse your modified JSON data in the success function with $.parseJSON

Note: Since it seems you are doing a cross-domain request, you must use jsonp, read more here:

http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: Thanks mpaf, Im sorry Im really no expert at this - how do I call that .ajax function, get the reuslt into a string, strip the first three <p> tags then parse the resultant JSON string, bearing in mind its not valid html either

Answer (score 1):

You should REALLY ask them to fix their JSON...

In the meantime, as a patch, you should download it as HTML content, preparse it (by removing the  tags) and then parse the resulting content as plain JSON.

But the above procedure is really a patch that should disappear when the JSON producers fixes it.

Comment: Getting them to fix it is NOT an option, how would I go about downloading it as HTML content, do you mean via Javascript calls?

Comment: exactly what @mpaf replied :). get the HTML via `$.ajax` and then modify the poorly written JSON and the result of the last operation goes straight to `$.parseJSON`