# Null value added to JSON request by servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

I request a servlet and it returns me JSON structure correctly but combined with "null"

```
null{"name":Maria,"totalPrice":17.49}
```

How can I remove null value in the first line?

I am using the following code to get `JSON-Servlet`:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    ((HttpURLConnection) (new URL(the_url)).openConnection()).getInputStream(),
        Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

String line;
String returnString = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    returnString += line;
}

reader.close();
out.write(returnString);
```

Comment: about null - could it be so it returns JSONP?  Try to access servlet url with ?jsonp=test or ?callback=test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *starting* with a `null` `String` variable, not an *empty* one, so when you add them together the `null` value gets replaced with `"null"`. Use `returnString = ""` instead. Better yet, use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}

reader.close();
out.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use for example

```
String yourNewJsonString = stringWithNull.substring(4);
```

as char with number 4 is `{` in your String.

BTW, please read [Parsing JSON Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java) and use it for parsing JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've replied a similar question ([How do I pre parse a JSON String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325267/how-do-i-pre-parse-a-json-string) )

The only problem here is that you **have** to pretend that the producer of JSON data produces them in a consistent manner. Work (if you can) on the JSON provider, not your client.

(being pragmatic) the reply form @eel-lee is what I would do if fixing the Servlet is unviable (?? really ??).